# Preventing fetching of computed columns in Entity Framework (EF)

Tags: entity-framework

I am inserting a lot of records at the same time. Though I have a timestamp field which I normally want to use, this is just a massive bulk import of approx. 1000 records.

Using a profiler, I noticed that after each insert, EF uses a select to retrieve the computed column. Is it possible to prevent this during a massive import where I am not interested in the timestamp because I will not be using the values that I just added in the same context?

Thanks in advance!